# VS2010 makes a copy of .Designer.cs-file

Tags: c#, xsd, dataset, typed

I'm using VS2010 (C#) for a WinForm database program. I've created a dataset, myds, which generates a couple of related files:

- myds.xsd
- myds.Designer.cs
- myds.xsc
- myds.xss

When I edit the xsd-file in design mode, perhaps just move around a TableAdapter, myds.Designer.cs makes a copy of itself to myds1.Designer.cs. After that I can't compile the program because the all the types and definitions becomes declared twice (they allready exists in the original myds.Designer.cs-file). It's quite annoying having to delete the copy every time I've made minor changes to that file. Why is it doing this, and can I prevent VS2010 from making this copy?

Comment: Is your myds.Designer.cs write protected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a known bug.

**Solution**

Unload the project containing your dataset.

Edit the project file (example 'datasetobjects.csproj') with text editor.
If you have another datasets you can find rows as:

```
 <None Include="My_DS.xsd">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSDataSetGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>My_DS.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
 </None>
```

And the problem is in the row  `<LastGenOutput>My_DS.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>`.
It may be misssing or incorrect for your DataSet.

[Bug link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532800/msdatasetgenerator-create-another-designer1-cs-file-for-my-typed-dataset#).

Answer (score 1):

Yes I had the same problem and the only way helped me was previous answer
Let visual create new designer file for you then go to project file (*.sln)
just change the designer name to your main dataset `<LastGenOutput>`(here you should rename).cs`</LastGenOutput>`
then you can delete the new designer file